# how to correct this?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

//public class AddressBookDemo implements ActionListener
public class AddressBookDemo
{
    ArrayList personsList;
    //PersonDAO pDAO;

JFrame appFrame;

//JLabel jlbSl;
JTextField jtfQuestion;
JButton  jbnClear, jbnForward, jbnBack, jbnFinish;

//String name, address, email;
//int phone;
//int recordNumber;  // used to naviagate using >> and << buttons 
Container cPane;


 public static void main(String args[]){
      new AddressBookDemo(); 
   }

public void createGUI(){

    /*Create a frame, get its contentpane and set layout*/
    appFrame = new JFrame("Address Book");

    cPane = appFrame.getContentPane();
    cPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //Arrange components on contentPane and set Action Listeners to each JButton
    arrangeComponents();

    appFrame.setSize(240,300);
    appFrame.setResizable(false);
    appFrame.setVisible(true);
    appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void arrangeComponents(){
    //jlbName = new JLabel("Name");

    jtfQuestion   = new JTextField(20);



    jbnClear  = new JButton("Clear");
    jbnForward = new JButton(">>");
    jbnBack    = new JButton("<<");
    jbnFinish    = new JButton("Finish");
    //GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx01 = new GridBagConstraints();
    //gridBagConstraintsx01.gridx = 0;
    //gridBagConstraintsx01.gridy = 0;
    //gridBagConstraintsx01.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    //cPane.add(jlbName, gridBagConstraintsx01);
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx04 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintsx04.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraintsx04.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gridBagConstraintsx04.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraintsx04.gridwidth = 2;
    gridBagConstraintsx04.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    cPane.add(jtfQuestion, gridBagConstraintsx04);

    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx12 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintsx12.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraintsx12.gridy = 5;
    gridBagConstraintsx12.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    cPane.add(jbnBack, gridBagConstraintsx12);

    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx14 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintsx14.gridx = 2;
    gridBagConstraintsx14.gridy = 5;
    gridBagConstraintsx14.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    cPane.add(jbnForward, gridBagConstraintsx14);

    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx15 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintsx15.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraintsx15.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gridBagConstraintsx15.gridy = 6;
    cPane.add(jbnClear, gridBagConstraintsx15);
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx16 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraintsx16.gridx = 2;
    gridBagConstraintsx16.gridy = 6;
    gridBagConstraintsx16.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    cPane.add(jbnFinish, gridBagConstraintsx16);

    //jbnClear.addActionListener(this);

    //jbnForward.addActionListener(this);
    //jbnBack.addActionListener(this);
    //jbnExit.addActionListener(this);

}
}
```

this code is not working.wat's wrong with it?
this gui contain a textbox which retrieves data from database,finish button,back,forward button.while running,it doesn't shows any output
i can't trace out the error.applet is not working

Comment: There is nothing in what you posted that uses a database AFAICT. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The method `createGUI` is never called, your frame should be empty or invisible at all, right?

Comment: You have just a bunch of GUI components but not code to make them do anything. I am not sure what you mean by it doesn't work, but I suspect you problem is you need to write more code.

Comment: it was an initial stage.i forgot to call createaGUI.thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
new AddressBookDemo();
```

to this:

```
new AddressBookDemo().createGUI();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AddressBookDemo addrbook = new AddressBookDemo(); 
addrbook.createGUI();
```